# PHP arrays, how does the syntax in the beginning bracket [''] format work?

Tags: php, arrays

I was looking up arrays and can't figure out  how the 'rows' is used?  does it become an object like 'cells' does?

```
$table['rows'][] = array('cells' => $cells);
```

Also, when you have

```
$variable [] []
```

Does this then become a multidimensional array?

Comment: 1) yes for one row contains multiple cells 2) yes

Comment: Does 'cells' go into the [] placeholder or the 'rows' object placeholder?

Comment: Rows is one of the keys in the array called $table. So instead of having an array with keys 1,2,3 etc. You name the key to something that makes sense, rows.

Comment: yes, $table['rows'][0] becomes cells as array in one row.

Comment: $table['rows'][0][0] = first cell value, $table['rows'][0][1] = second cell value and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 you can use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

```
// doing this steps
$table['row'][] = ['cell' => 1];
$table['row'][] = ['cell' => 2];
$table['row'][] = ['cell' => 3];

// you will receive
['row'] => [
    ['cell' => 1],
    ['cell' => 2],
    ['cell' => 3]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It will put an array under `rows` key in `$table` array like so:

```
array(1) {
  ["rows"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["cells"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
```

2. as for the second question:

   `php > $variable = [];
   php > $variable[][] = 1;
   php > var_dump($variable);
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     array(1) {
       [0]=>
       int(1)
     }
   }`

   You can always experiment using php's REPL shell: `php -a`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `$table` is an associative array and the element inside `$table` with the key `'rows'` is itself an array.

Answer (score 1):

before going with the quick answer, I just want to mention that this is very easy to test for yourself and get a quick answer. If you have a working version of PHP working on your dev environment, you could create s simple php file and run it in CLI. Something like this :

```
<?php
$array[][] = 'HelloWorld';
var_dump($array);
?>
```

And then when you run : $ php myFile.php
You would get :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it sets both array keys to 0. That is right, they are going to auto-increment. If you already have some keys defined on this level, it will also start at 0. So, on the same level you had 'foo' and 'bar' as existing keys and you added $array[] = 'something' then you would have foo, bar, 0 as keys in your array.

This also reword your initial statement, cells is not an 'object' but rather a 'key'. It is the name of the node in the array. You could access it using foreach, for exemple, like this :

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){

}
```